# Dampp-chaser Piano Life Saver System Placement

Tags: piano

I have a model P2 35 Wurlitzer. I would like to know where to place a Dampp-Chaser Piano Life Saver System on it... I tried to research where the bar with cord goes, no luck

Comment: Pretty pointless downvoting by someone - but the reason is most likely that there isn't enough information here to go on. A pic may also help.

Comment: @Cynthia Woods- I've searched for P2 35 Wurlitzer and came up with nothing, please double check the Model Number, thank you.

Comment: I think the OP is referring to  the Wurlitzer Opus Theatre Organ, Model 235 - https://rivieratheatre.org/about/the-mighty-wurlitzer/